# How to change the response_type to id_token in authorization URL for implicit Oauth2 flow

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have following OpenAPI configuration

```
   new OpenAPI()
                .components(
                        new Components()
                                .addSecuritySchemes("oAuthScheme", new SecurityScheme()
                                        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2)
                                        .description("This API uses OAuth 2 with the implicit grant flow.")
                                        .flows(new OAuthFlows()
                                                .implicit(new OAuthFlow()
                                                        .authorizationUrl("http://example.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize")
                                                        .scopes(new Scopes()
                                                                .addString("openid", "read user information")
                                                        )

                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                )
```

When I click on Authorize button on swagger UI, it is generating following URL

```
http://example.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?nonce=nonce&response_type=token&client_id=client-id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fswagger-ui%2Foauth2-redirect.html&scope=openid&state=U2F0IEphbiAwMiAyMDIxID
```

I want response_type as id_token in place of token. is the any way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using openidconnect.

You should switch to SecurityScheme = OPENIDCONNECT and fill your openIdConnectUrl url. As result, you will get id_token in the response.

Comment: URL that is generated on clicking Authorize for implicit flow is having response_type as token when security scheme is OpenIDConnect.